# Hover on google chart acting weird on firefox

Tags: javascript, css, google-visualization

When adding a hover event to google chart svg element the results are different between firefox and chrome (chrome is doing what I would expect).
What I would like to achieve is the ability for the user to hover on a chart and not care how close he is to the line - the hover should be smooth and easy to use.

Here is the relevant plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/2IF2BnX0tS2wznAUr5bs?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    google.charts.load('current', {
        callback: drawChart,
        packages: ['corechart']
    });

    function drawChart() {
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable({
            cols: [
                { id: 'x', label: 'Num', type: 'number' },
                { id: 'y', label: 'Fn', type: 'number' }
            ]
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            var xValue = { v: i };
            var yValue = { v: i };

            // add data row
            dataTable.addRow([
                xValue,
                yValue
            ]);
        }

        var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
        var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: 'LineChart',
            dataTable: dataTable,
            options: {
                hAxis: {
                    gridlines: {
                        color: 'transparent'
                    },
                    title: 'Hover here is also fine'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    trigger: "none"
                },
                vAxis: {
                    gridlines: {
                        color: 'transparent'
                    },
                    title: 'Hover here is OK'
                }
            }
        });

        // add hover line
        google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
            var svgParent = container.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
            var layout = chart.getChart().getChartLayoutInterface();
            var lineHeight = layout.getBoundingBox('chartarea').height - 18;
            var lineTop = layout.getBoundingBox('chartarea').top;

            var hoverLine = container.getElementsByTagName('rect')[0].cloneNode(true);
            hoverLine.setAttribute('y', lineTop);
            hoverLine.setAttribute('height', lineHeight);
            hoverLine.setAttribute('width', '1');
            hoverLine.setAttribute('stroke', 'none');
            hoverLine.setAttribute('stroke-width', '0');
            hoverLine.setAttribute('fill', '#cccccc');
            hoverLine.setAttribute('x', 0);
            svgParent.appendChild(hoverLine);

            svgParent.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
                hoverLine.setAttribute('x', e.offsetX);
            });
        });

        chart.draw(container);
    }
</script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Hover on the chart with chrome to see the expected behaiour.
Hover on the chart with firefox to see the issue.
Any idea how to solve this? is this a google chart bug? Am I adding an event listener to the wrong element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the children tags in your svg are capturing the mousemove events (which makes since due to event propogation).

Simply add a pointer-events:none to those children elements (I recommended to use an id for that svg element)

```css
svg *{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
  google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    cols: [
      {id: 'x', label: 'Num', type: 'number'},
      {id: 'y', label: 'Fn', type: 'number'}
    ]
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var xValue = { v: i };
    var yValue = { v: i };

    // add data row
    dataTable.addRow([
      xValue,
      yValue
    ]);
  }

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    dataTable: dataTable,
    options: {
      hAxis: {
        gridlines: {
          color: 'transparent'
        },
        title: 'Hover here is also fine'
      },
      tooltip: {
        trigger: "none"
      },
      vAxis: {
        gridlines: {
          color: 'transparent'
        },
        title: 'Hover here is OK'
      }
    }
  });

  // add hover line 
  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var svgParent = container.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    var layout = chart.getChart().getChartLayoutInterface();
    var lineHeight = layout.getBoundingBox('chartarea').height - 18;
    var lineTop = layout.getBoundingBox('chartarea').top;

    var hoverLine = container.getElementsByTagName('rect')[0].cloneNode(true);
    hoverLine.setAttribute('y', lineTop);
    hoverLine.setAttribute('height', lineHeight);
    hoverLine.setAttribute('width', '1');
    hoverLine.setAttribute('stroke', 'none');
    hoverLine.setAttribute('stroke-width', '0');
    hoverLine.setAttribute('fill', '#cccccc');
    hoverLine.setAttribute('x', 0);
    svgParent.appendChild(hoverLine);
    
    svgParent.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
      hoverLine.setAttribute('x', e.offsetX);
    });
  });

  chart.draw(container);
}
</script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked like charm, thanks a lot! do you know what causes this? I really don't understand why this should work...

Comment: when you hover over your svg element..the children gets that hover and the e.offsetX position is calculated from the position of the children element instead of the parent due to event propagation